# VPN - Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: windows-7, vpn

I've set up a VPN connection to my work network on my home PC - running Windows 7

It connects fine.

Once connected, I can ping machines that are on my work network using my home pc, however, if I try to RDP to them, it doesn't connect...

It seems to initially connect, 
It asks me for the logon user / password, and when I set them, and click OK, it gets stuck on a screen saying:

"Securing Remote Connection"

Eventually it pops up saying

"This computer can't connect to the remote computer.

Try connecting again. If the problem persists, contact the owner of the remote computer or your network administrator"

I know this computer is configured to allow remote connections etc... (and I've tried it with several different machines on the remote network)

Any ideas what i've set wrong?

Comment: Give us more details on the VPN connection...

Comment: Turn off the remote and local PC firewalls to see if the problem persists. If it goes away, we've narrowed it down and can start looking at firewall rules.

Comment: what details about the VPN connection would you need?

Comment: Need details on what kinda of VPN connection? Cisco VPN...?  Sounds like a firewall issue to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Win 7 machine, start Remote Desktop Connection. Click on Options and go to the Advanced tab. For Server Authentication, do you have "Do not connect"? If so, knock it back to "Warn me" and try again.

Answer (score 2):

Validate that you can communicate with the remote IP over TCP 3389. You can validate this via telnet:

telnet [remoteServerIP] 3389

If you get a connection refused look at any local firewall software then validate ACL's on both networks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've been using a standard ping.  Try a ping with a larget packet size.

```
ping -l 1500 server.ip
```

If this fails and the standard ping works you have an MTU issue at some point.  Keep lowering the number after -l until your pings transit properly.  We'll need to know the details of your VPN concentrator to give instructions on how to fix that.  It can be set at the remote endpoint and firewall.